# Firebase Storage : Как получить ссылку для загрузки?

Tags: firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android, firebaseanalytics, firebase-web-api

У меня есть код, который должен вернуть мне ссылку на скачивание, но он не работает, ошибка в том, что он неправильно написан. Подскажите, как правильно получить ссылку на скачивание из Firebase Storage Firebase Storage.

вот мой код:

```
            // Create a reference to the file we want to download
            FirebaseStorage storage = new FirebaseStorage("*********.appspot.com");
            var starsRef = storage.Child("test.txt");
            string link = starsRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл ответ: кому понадобится вот:

```
        private void button28_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a reference to the file we want to download
            _ = getLinkAsync();
            getLinkAsync();

        }
        public async Task getLinkAsync()
        {
            FirebaseStorage storage = new FirebaseStorage("firstbd-****.appspot.com");
            var starsRef = storage.Child("test.txt");
            string link = await starsRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(link);
        }
```